# Python Speech Recognition Library

Tags: library, python, speech-recognition

I'm looking for a library in python that has fairly accurate speech recognition. It would preferably return a string indicating what was said, so that I can work with the string to do other things. Thanks!!!

I looked at [this related question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621319/good-voice-input-api-library-in-python) but I don't think we're asking the same thing.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239080/getting-started-with-speech-recognition-and-python) is closer to what you want.

Comment: For what language? English?

Comment: Yes, it should be in English.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/download/):

- free and open source
- recognizer library written in C but provides Python bindings
- often mentioned as one of the best open source speech recognition engines

When looking for a speech recognition software for Linux a while ago, I was told that CMU Sphinx' accuracy is significantly lower than Dragon (I'd be curious if anyone here has a benchmark Sphinx vs Dragon). However, if your voice recordings are in a well restricted domain, you might be able to train CMU Sphinx well enough.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAI's [Whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper) (off-line, MIT license, Python 3.9, CLI) yields some highly accurate transcription. To use (tested on Ubuntu 20.04 x64 LTS):

```
conda create -y --name whisperpy39 python==3.9
conda activate whisperpy39
pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git 
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ffmpeg
whisper recording.wav
whisper recording.wav --model large
```

If using an Nvidia 3090 GPU, add the following after `conda activate whisperpy39`

```
pip install -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
conda install pytorch==1.10.1 torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.0 -c pytorch
```

it can be used as a Python lib, [e.g.](https://github.com/openai/whisper):

```
import whisper

model = whisper.load_model("base")

# load audio and pad/trim it to fit 30 seconds
audio = whisper.load_audio("audio.mp3")
audio = whisper.pad_or_trim(audio)

# make log-Mel spectrogram and move to the same device as the model
mel = whisper.log_mel_spectrogram(audio).to(model.device)

# detect the spoken language
_, probs = model.detect_language(mel)
print(f"Detected language: {max(probs, key=probs.get)}")

# decode the audio
options = whisper.DecodingOptions()
result = whisper.decode(model, mel, options)

# print the recognized text
print(result.text)
```

---

Performance info below.

Model inference time:

| Size | Parameters | English-only model | Multilingual model | Required VRAM | Relative speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tiny | 39 M | `tiny.en` | `tiny` | ~1 GB | ~32x |
| base | 74 M | `base.en` | `base` | ~1 GB | ~16x |
| small | 244 M | `small.en` | `small` | ~2 GB | ~6x |
| medium | 769 M | `medium.en` | `medium` | ~5 GB | ~2x |
| large | 1550 M | N/A | `large` | ~10 GB | 1x |

WER on several corpus from https://cdn.openai.com/papers/whisper.pdf:

[image]

WER on several languages from https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/main/language-breakdown.svg:

[image]